# Can publishing on arXiv create copyright issues?

Tags: publications, arxiv, online-publication

As an undergraduate I'm relatively new to academia. I was wondering if publishing a paper on arXiv could potentially be an issue if I were to want to get the same paper in, say, Nature, for why would Nature be okay with their material being openly available online? Isn't there a copyright issue here?

Comment: arXiv is not considered a "publication" venue, but a pre-print server. As such, most STEM journals explicitly allow its use, sometimes with caveats about citing or not citing the actual publication, allowing uploads before but not after journal acceptance, etc. Each journal has its own rules that you would have to follow.

Comment: Emphasize - each journal has its own rules. Those like Nature at the top of the heap might be especially picky. Ask them or find their policies online.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nature especially states how pre-prints should be handled:

> Preprints
>
> Nature Research journals support posting of primary research manuscripts on community preprint servers such as arXiv and bioRxiv.  Preprint posting is not considered prior publication and will not jeopardize consideration at Nature Research journals.  [...] Authors posting preprints are asked to respect our policy on communications with the media (http://www.nature.com/authors/policies/embargo.html).
>
> [...]
>
> The original submitted version of the manuscript (the version that has not undergone peer review) may be posted at any time.  Authors should disclose details of preprint posting, including DOI, upon submission of the manuscript to a Nature Research journal.

Taken from Nature's webside about [Publishing licences and compliance with open access mandates](https://www.nature.com/authors/policies/license.html).

**TL;DR** You can post your pre-print on arXiv prior to its submission to Nature.

**Important:** These condition may not only vary by publisher but by journal/conference.